# MySql Query results in a specific way

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `my_table1` and `my_table2`.

`my_table1` contains numbers from 1 to 10 and `my_table2` contains letters a, b, c and d.

I want to do a query which returns the following:

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
2 a
2 b
2 c
2 d
```

All the way until the end.

Is there any possible way to do this in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a cross join. You can write that in the simple (old) form by just selecting `select * from table1, table2`, but this is outdated syntax, and your queries will become *very* hard to read if you mix this syntax with the more modern explicit joins that were introduced in 1992. So, I'd chose to write the explicit `cross join`.

Also, it looks like you want the results sorted. If you're lucky this happens automatically, but you cannot be sure that this will always happen, so best to specify it if you need it. If not, omit the `order by` clause, because it does make the query slower.

```
select
  n.nr,
  l.letter
from
  my_table1 n
  cross join my_table2 l
order by
  n.nr,
  l.letter
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. In this case, there is no need to sort the the results, so as you said I omitted the order by clause.

Answer (score 1):

That is a `CROSS JOIN`, in MySQL equivalent to an `INNER JOIN` or a regular comma:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table1, my_table2;
```

cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html